# Android : How to observe three different sql queries and get multiple different results using RXJava

Tags: android, sqlite, observable, rx-java, android-room

I want to observe three different sql queries which return three different kind of result. For this I have tried the below code.

```
var searchTicketsObservable = ticketHoldersRepository.getSearhTickets(eventId, searchQuery.value.toString()).toObservable()
var verifiedObservable = verifiedCredentialsRepository.listVerifiedCredentials(eventId).toObservable()
var blackListed = blacklistRepository.getBlacklistedItems(eventId).toObservable()
Observable.merge(searchTicketsObservable, verifiedObservable, blackListed)
.subscribeOn(rxSchedulers.io)
    .observeOn(rxSchedulers.mainThread)
    .subscribeBy(
        onNext = { result ->
        },
        onError = {
        }
    ).addTo(disposables)
```

I am new to RXJava. I dont think this is the right approach to observe three queries and get three different results. I am also doing this operation on the basis of manual search which the user can type and search. Based on the search input, this observer get the result from the local database. Could someone help me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!